# Exporting data to CSV file and ignoring the left side index

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am exporting data to a csv file on python and I want to ignore the left hand side numbering from 0-4

[image]

So that I get a dataset in my csv file like below:

[image]

I have tried coding:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(distance.pairwise(points_df[['x','y']].to_numpy()),  columns=points_df.Location.unique(), index=points_df.Location.unique())


df_drop = df.iloc[: , 1:]

df_drop.to_csv('points.csv')
```

but this is my solution:

[image]

I can just change my csv file by changing the numbers, but I am going to be using a lot of data points so I want to be able to code this on python.

Comment: If I understand you issue correctly, you should be able to create a csv file without the df index simply by using ```df.to_csv('filepath, index=False)```

Comment: `help(pd.DataFrame.to_csv)` will show the options available.

Answer (score 0):

use `index=False`

This is how it should look like:

```py
df_drop.to_csv('points.csv', index=False)
```